# How do I change the font size in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, fontsize

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[paperheight = 140mm,% comprimento 
            paperwidth  = 200mm,% altura
            margin      = 10mm  % tamanho da margem
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setmainfont[Color=brown]{Tangerine}

\begin{document}
    Normal pleasure of your company is requested
\end{document}
```

I'm making a wedding invitation and I'm not sure how do it using LuaLaTeX.

I want to set, in `\setmainfont`, the default color and size but I don't know how. I'm able to set the color, as in the example, but not the size at the same time.
`\setmainfont[SizeFeatures={Size=30}]{Tangerine}` sets the size, but I don't know how put it together. Is it possible?

Furthermore, how do I change the font size in the middle of the document? I tried `\Huge` but got an error.

Comment: You should _not_ use `fontenc` _and_ `fontspec` with LuaLaTeX; `fontspec` is enough.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`\Huge` did not work because you used the `minimal` document class, which does not provide any font size commands. Use the usual `article` instead.

You shouldn't also need to set font size with `fontspec`, too. Use any of these options:

- To set a default font size document-wise, pass one of the options `10pt`, `11pt` or `12pt` to the document class.
- Use the usual font size commands (`\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, etc.).
- If none of the above have the size you need, select it manually with `\fontsize{<size>}{<leading>}`. A `\selectfont` command has to follow *immediately* after.

The two latter options also can be used document-wise: just put them right after `\begin{document}` outside any groups.

To sum up, an example document:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setmainfont[Color=brown]{Linux Libertine}

\begin{document}

Lorem {\Huge ipsum} dolor {\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\selectfont sit} amet.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

The option `SizeFeatures` is not meant to *set* a size. It should be used to set features which should be activated/used only for some font sizes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setmainfont[SizeFeatures={{Size=-11,Color=red},
                           {Size=11-30,Color=blue},
                           {Size=30-,Color=green}}]{Arial}
\begin{document}

normal red text 
\large larger blue text 
\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont very large green Text
\end{document}
```