# How to use fontspec to set normalsize to 11pt?

Tags: luatex, fontsize

I'm writing a document where it is important that the font specification is times new roman and the font is 11pt.

This question [Where and why does (LuaLa)TeX scale down the requested base font size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264624/where-and-why-does-lualatex-scale-down-the-requested-base-font-size) provides a discusseion regarding why this is so (geometric progression) and states that it's easy to change using `fontspec` but does not provide an example.

This answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46089/89786 shows how it can be done with snippets of text. But I want to redefine `\normalsize` to be precisely 11.pt globally, but not the other fonts.

How do i do it? The following code shows that the `\normalsize` font is 10.95pt.

```
\documentclass[english,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{mathptmx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand\thefontsize[2]{{#1 The current font size is: #2 \f@size pt\par}}

\makeatother

\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont 

\begin{document}
\thefontsize\tiny{tiny}
\thefontsize\scriptsize{scriptsize}
\thefontsize\footnotesize{footnotesize}
\thefontsize\small{small}
\thefontsize\normalsize{normalsize}
\thefontsize\large{large}
\thefontsize\Large{Large}
\thefontsize\LARGE{LARGE}
\thefontsize\huge{huge}
\thefontsize\Huge{Huge}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For historical reasons, LaTeX considers 11pt to be 10.95pt. Now, 10.95pt is 717619sp, 11pt is 720896sp and 11bp (PostScript points) is 723599sp. The 0.5% difference between 11pt and 10.95pt is negligible (0.5pt is 0.18mm, or 0.007in); similarly negligible is the 0.8% difference between 11bp and 10.95pt.

Comment: I agree that the difference is negligible. But that does not mean that i don't want to have precisely 11 pt.

Comment: @MikaelFremling but do you want precisely 11pt in TeX units or precisely 11pt in the units used by most other software (PostScript, Word, etc) which is 11bp in TeX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I would guess that i want 11bp. It that case one has 1bp = 0.99628bp so 11bp = 10.959pt, correct?(https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm)

Comment: @MikaelFremling no you converted in wrong direction, a bp is a big point so 11bp is more than 11pt it's 11*72.27/72 =11.04125  (or actually 11.04124 as shown by tex) although .04pt really isn't very much to worry about..., egreg's accepted answer will give you 11pt not 11bp.

Comment: Similar question [fontsize - How to set font size at exactly 11 pt? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167402/how-to-set-font-size-at-exactly-11-pt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the LaTeX default to be 11 instead of 10.95. You may also want to do other roundings.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@xipt{11}
\renewcommand\@xviipt{17}
\renewcommand\@xxpt{20}
\renewcommand\@xxvpt{25}
\makeatother

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\thefontsize[2]{{#1 The current font size is: #2 \f@size pt\par}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thefontsize\tiny{tiny}
\thefontsize\scriptsize{scriptsize}
\thefontsize\footnotesize{footnotesize}
\thefontsize\small{small}
\thefontsize\normalsize{normalsize}
\thefontsize\large{large}
\thefontsize\Large{Large}
\thefontsize\LARGE{LARGE}
\thefontsize\huge{huge}
\thefontsize\Huge{Huge}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For math, I recommend `\usepackage{newtxmath}` rather than `mathptmx`.