# How to accurately set the font size for different lines?

Tags: luatex, fontsize

I need to create the cover page for my thesis.
The university provides the specifications like this:

```
‐ Univerity logo.
‐ Faculty name: Palatino Lynotipe, 16pt, capitalized.
‐ Department: Palatino Lynotipe, 15pt, lowercase.
‐ Title: Palatino Lynotipe, 17pt, lowercase.
‐ Author: Palatino Lynotipe, 14pt, lowercase
‐ Director: Palatino Lynotipe, 14pt, Lowercase
‐ City, month, year: Palatino Lynotipe, 17pt, lowercase.
```

The main text in the thesis has to be 11pt.

Most people does it with MS Word, I'm using LuaTeX instead because my thesis is very technical, with a lot of graphics and equations.

Then I'm using

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}
```

My question is...
How can I specify the sizes for the different lines on the cover page?
Using words such as \Large \large \LARGE \Huge and so on is very inaccurate and I really don't know the final size.

How can I know the Pagella Size that matches the size of the Palatino font?

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/setting-a-document-in-ms-word-12pt-12bp can help

Comment: Maybe I've found an easier way 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46087/how-do-i-change-the-font-size-in-lualatex
 {\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\selectfont sit}
What are the first and second argument numbers?

Comment: The first argument is the fontsize, the second the baselineskip which should normally be about 1.4 times the font size. The reason why I linked the other question: a font size of x pt in word is not necessarily x pt in latex. If you must follow an exact requirement about the size, have a careful look into your log file if the font size you specified is actually available or replaced by the next available size.

Comment: @samcarter IIRC, the “normal” \baselineskip is 1.2 times the fontsize, not 1.4. :)

Comment: @frougon Argh, of course you are right!

Comment: Is the TeXGyrePagellaX fontsize approximately equivalent to the Palatino Lynotipe fontsize?